# Is thermodynamics mainly related with boundary processes?

Tags: thermodynamics

If you have a reversible process, then everything is easy because the full container of substance would have homogenous properties, but, how would you deal with assigning state variables for irreversible processes? The variables vary both spatially and temporally, so like, it must be impossible to concretely label variables for the system.

As per my experience, I've seen some bypasses to this problem by making certain quantities be based on a certain part of the system. For example, in the $ \int \frac{dq_{irrev} }{T}$ integral, we refer the $T$ underneath as the temperature of surroundings rather than that of the whole system.

Another example to support my claim: Consider the term 'isolated system', this system has $ q= w= 0 =\Delta U = \Delta V$ , this means that we care not at all for any internal process which may occur in gas. As in, though the boundary work is zero, there may be some internal energy shifts inside the system.

The above led me to the following conclusion that most thermodynamic quantities are fundamentally speaking of the behaviors at the boundary of the system. Is this claim correct? why /why not?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well your question. The state variables (when they make sense to exist) are the same as in regular thermodynamics of equilibrium. But as you say, this time they are varying across the system, so for example temperature is "well defined" only locally, in any infinitesimal parts of the system, say. You can still work out using thermodynamics relations. That's even how one can derive the heat equation I would say.

Comment: So even though one cannot speak of a temperature of a non uniformly heated metal rod, one can still speak about its temperature at any point (in both space and time).

Comment: From my understanding, experimentally speaking, we figure out the variables by sampling any small volume of gas and finding the variables from there in a prcoess in equilibrium and that allows us to write out equation

Comment: now, if I take pressure, how would I speak of it? each point difference pressure. Maybe volume is okay because we define volume as volume of container

Comment: You would speak of it just like temperature or any other state variable. It makes sense locally, unless you're dealing with an extreme condition.

Comment: That would be quite complicated to do, by that logic, you would need a multivariable function of space and time to describe everything

Comment: Well, you have fluxes and generalized forces, add the laws of thermodynamics, etc. and you have a fully describable dynamics of your system.

Comment: I think you need to differentiate between thermodynamic properties that vary spatially from those that vary in time. Equilibrium means properties do not vary in time. That doesn’t necessarily mean they can’t vary spatially, as in the case of the temperature in solids under steady heat flow conditions.

Comment: @Buraian BTW your statement about $T$ in the integral is not quite correct. It is the temperature at the boundary between the system and surroundings. Only if the surroundings is a thermal reservoir is it then the temperature of the surroundings.

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence

Comment: @BobD I do not fully agree. Thermodynamics equilibrium requires a well defined temperature. When variables do not vary in time anymore, we are talking about a steady state (as in the case of thermoelectricity for example, when we wait long enough so that a constant grad T is established and this generates a voltage), but this is not the thermodynamics equilibrium. In fact, this is non equilibrium thermodynamics!

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson I'm not quite sure what part of what I said you disagree with. It seems to me you are supporting my argument that temperatures can vary spatially (e.g., the constant grad you speak of) and still be in thermal equilibrium as long as they don't vary in time.

Comment: @BobD Thermodynamics equilibrium requires that the temperature be constant spatially. When there is a temperature gradient, there is a diffusion process. It doesn't matter that the temperature does not vary in time anymore (i.e. that the steady state is reached), this isn't thermodynamics equilibrium. Wikipedia got that part right in the first sentences of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_equilibrium.

Comment: @BobD in that steady state where there is a grad T, dS/dt is non zero, i.e. entropy is being produced in time. This isn't thermodynamics equilibrium.