# Work done in Free Expansion of ideal gases

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

My textbook says that work done by a gas is loosely defined as the product of the pressure of system and the corresponding change in volume. It also states that work done in free expansion is zero because there is zero external pressure.

But my question is that, if work done is due to pressure of ideal gas and not external pressure then in free expansion there very much is a pressure of gas. Why do we then conclude that work done is zero?

Comment: Due to how we define work. $dW= -P_{ext} dV$

Comment: [Not the downvoter], but I can also say it another way. Suppose a body is moving at constant velocity in presence of no forces, no work is done, right? So similarly imagine all the gas molecules pushign against nothing (Free space), no work would be done still. Also free expansion is irreversible process.. so things like pressure temperature don't make sense as they are only definable for reversible one

Comment: [Please see this question I posted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578754/is-thermodynamics-mainly-related-with-boundary-processes)

Comment: @Buraian Not only that.  In a rapid expansion, from fluid mechanics, we know that we need to include viscous stresses in determining the compressive stresses that the gas exerts.  If we properly include viscous stresses, we conclude that the force per unit area that the gas exerts on its surroundings is equal to the external pressure that the surroundings exert on the gas, namely zero.  So if we calculate the work that the gas does on its surroundingsuing the gas force per unit area we also include that it does no work.

Comment: These answers make a lot of sense, thank you!